# Scanning messages for specific words

Tags: python, nextcord

I have created a list of words that the bot has to look for in messages sent to then upon finding those words it has a few sentences to reply back with. I came up with this but when run it does not work.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if any(word in message for word in history_words):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter_history_phrases))
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation mentions that the `message` parameter (https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#nextcord.on_message) is of type [Message](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#nextcord.Message).

To actually check the text, you need to do `message.content`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check(message, lookfor):

    wordfound = False

    for look in lookfor:
        if look in message:
            wordfound = True
            break

    return wordfound
```

`Lookfor` needs to be a table/array.